# IE8 crashes while loading some pages, site uses Modernizr, HTML5shiv, @font-face, stripmq, BlessCSS, Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, font-face, modernizr, html5shiv

I'm working on a large-scale site which is set to launch soon. They still have almost 15% of their desktop audience on IE8, so we must support it.

We're using a custom build of Modernizr (v 2.6.3) with HTML5shiv included. We're also using stripmq (we took out respond.js to eliminate another set of relatively unnecessary variables). The crux of our issue seems to be with @font-face. We're linking to some font css and font files on an external site, where they serve .eot as MIME-TYPE application/octet-stream (seemingly successfully, despite all references on teh interwebs). We're also linking to some local fonts, but using MIME-TYPE application/vnd.ms-object, as recommended (Bootstrap's Glyphicons, an Icomoon custom set, StateFace).

The crashing is unpredictable from page-to-page, and from environment-to-environment. We're linking to the .eot files first, before loading the rest of the css (where the other sources are provided) because that alleviated the multi-source issue in IE8 as of a few days ago. We'd also thought we fixed it previously by linking to those few font files externally instead of locally (with their differing MIME-TYPE), and by removing one of our custom fonts, but over time we're still getting crashing despite all that.

We tried moving the .eot file definitions to the body, per another StackOverflow post, with no success. Removing all CSS from the site has in the past prevented the crashing (though thats not an option). We also verified that none of our @font-face definitions are inside media queries.

---

An approximation of the beginning of our document (I can't share full code sample):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js gt-ie8"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

css for ie fonts
the rest of the css (split intelligently in two by BlessCss after minification via CssMin, using the imports option)

Modernizr (v 2.6.3)

stripmq to strip out media queries and serve only styles applicable to 1280px wide (conditional only for IE)

the rest of the scripts (including jQuery v. 1.11.1) are loaded in the body.

---

UPDATE: The final step to avoiding the crashing was getting our CDN to not deliver the content with this obscure header: https://rogerkeays.com/blog/internet-explorer-meets-the-vary-header

Comment: Not using pie.htc again right? :-p